# htaccess Server-side WEBP detection in conjunction with WordPress htaccess rules

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webp

I have my htaccess file setup like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # check if browser accepts webp
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp 

  # check if file is jpg or png
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\.(jpe?g|png)$

  # check if corresponding webp file exists image.png -> image.webp
  RewriteCond %1\.webp -f

  # serve up webp instead
  RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>

AddType image/webp .webp
```

Which works really well in a test directory, and shows a webp image if one is present. However, when I tried to use the same .htaccess rules in conjunction with WordPress' pretty permalinks rewrite rules, the rules then break.

This is WordPress' default rule (if your subdir is called DPA)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /DPA/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /DPA/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I get the following error at the server if I try and access the jpg file directly:

```
The requested URL /wp-content/themes/dpa/assets/img/home-page/sliders/strategy-1650.webp was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I suppose this is because WordPress looks for files in the root and messes up the actual location of the image file.

Does anyone know rewrite rules well enough on apache to make the two rules compatible with each other?

Thanks!

Patrick

Comment: Are you putting your rules above or below WordPress's? I usually keep WordPress's rules all the way at the bottom. Also, have you tried adding the "last rule" flag `L` to your rewrite? `[T=image/webp,E=accept:1,L]`

Comment: I tried above and below but it didn't seem to make a difference. I'll try that L flag now

Comment: Try both above and `L` so that it will kick in first and WordPress won't get involved at all.

Comment: Nope sorry its still not getting the files. Makes no difference whether its above or below the wordpress block, I changed `RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1]` to `RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1,L]`

Comment: Hmm... I just tried and your rule works perfectly fine for me. Can you post the path to the JPG that's causing the above error so we can see how it is getting mangled?

Comment: Sorry Chris, I forgot to mention I was working in a sub directory! See my answer, it works fine for me now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /DPA/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /DPA/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /DPA/
  # check if browser accepts webp
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp 

  # check if file is jpg or png
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)\.(jpe?g|png)$

  # check if corresponding webp file exists image.png -> image.webp
  RewriteCond %1\.webp -f

  # serve up webp instead
  RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>

AddType image/webp .webp
```

I added RewriteBase /DPA/ to the webp check and now it works fine.

I just realised I included the default WordPress pretty permalinks code, but it should have been the one for directories. I will edit the question now.